# Handling exceptions in preStart in actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have a service that has a supervisor responsible for build children actors and handling their exceptions.

`ServiceMain -> Supervisor -> DiscoveryActor`

To build the `DiscoveryActor` I call the following

```
Await.result(supervisor ? (Props[Discovery], "Discovery"), Duration.create(60, SECONDS)) match {
    case actor: ActorRef =>
      discoveryActor = actor

    case ex: Exception =>
      logger.error("Failed to initialize discovery actor", ex)
      sys.exit(1)
}
```

Which gets handled by this code in `Supervisor`

```
def receive = {
  case p: Props => sender() ! context.actorOf(p)

  case (p: Props, s: String) => sender() ! context.actorOf(p, s)
}
```

It is expected of the `DiscoveryActor` to throw an exception in `preStart()` if it can't research a host as configured. The exception `ApiConnectionException` is thrown by the actor and is captured by akka and turned into a `ActorInitializationException`.

I have tired catching this exception in the Await and with the superviseStrategy as below

```
override val supervisorStrategy =
  AllForOneStrategy() {
    case _: Exception                =>       Escalate
  }
```

But neither of these have managed to catch it, what I am attempting to do is catch such exception and exit the application.

If anyone can point out where I am going wrong or what I have missed then I shall be very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simplified your code a bit just to get straight to the root of the problem. You can copy it and paste it into your editor. It uses ***ScalaTest*** suite.

`SupervisorStrategy` defined in `Supervisor` actor **does** catch an exception thrown by `Discovery` actor in `preStart` method. You might want to have a closer look at your own code.

Your `Await` block is trying to catch an exception, but it's not possible in this context. The `Exception` is thrown by `Discovery` actor, not send as a message. Ask pattern (?) you use simply awaits for a message to arrive though. Only use of `SupervisorStrategy` can get you back a thrown exception. Instead of escalating exception in your `Supervisor` you could send a message to your application Guardian actor saying that initialization failed so the application should exit. Or do it directly in your `Supervisor`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit    
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Escalate
import akka.actor._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.testkit.{ImplicitSender, TestKit}
import akka.util.Timeout
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuiteLike, Matchers}

import scala.concurrent.Await

abstract class ActorSuite(systemName: String)
  extends TestKit(ActorSystem(systemName))
  with FunSuiteLike
  with ImplicitSender
  with Matchers
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override def afterAll {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }
}

class FailingActorInitializationSuite extends ActorSuite("failing-system") {


  test("run it") {

    val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props[Supervisor])
    var discoveryActor: ActorRef = null

    implicit val timeout = Timeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    Await.result(
      supervisor ?(Props[Discovery], "Discovery"), timeout.duration) match {
      case actor: ActorRef =>
        discoveryActor = actor
    }
  }
}

class Supervisor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override val supervisorStrategy =
    AllForOneStrategy() {
      case e: Exception =>
        log.error(s"Caught an exception [${e.getCause.getMessage}] and escalating")
        Escalate
    }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case (p: Props, s: String) => sender() ! context.actorOf(p, s)
  }
}

class Discovery extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    super.preStart()
    throw new RuntimeException("Can't create")
  }

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej! I see what you mean by my code pretty much being the same and after cleaning it up a bit its now work, odd but isn't that the fun about programming? :D